# How to print a list with double quotes in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

When I print a list in dart, it prints without double quotes like this-

[image]

How do I print this list with double quotes around each element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
wordlewords.forEach((word){
   print('"$word"');
});
```

Comment: you are welcome. If you solved the issue please mark the answer as correct

Answer (score 2):

Add `\` before `"` to skip there function (count it as an normal character).

**Example**:
[image]